# Facebook Credit in website

Tags: facebook

I had problem when tried to implement Facebook Credit into my website..

First step I make an app on facebook..
Then activated the credit and register my company to accept the payment..
I write website destination for callback.php
that's all my preparation..

then the test begin..
I create simple button to pay with facebook on my website u can check on http://the-rhs.co.cc/fb/
I use https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/489/ for references..
the button is shown, but when I click the button I got 
error code 1151
error description : Sorry, but this app may not be eligible to accept Facebook Credits. If this app has accepted credits before, please try again.)
Resolving : asking for facebook administrator.

I'm little bit confuse and don't know how to fix the problem..
anyone, please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits only work in facebook canvas apps.

```
The Facebook Credits API enables a user to use credits as a method for purchasing  
digital and virtual goods within a Facebook canvas application.  
Please note: the credits api is not yet available for use by  external websites 
but only on canvas iframe applications.
```

Might that be your case..?

Comment: Finally.. thanks bro.. it's really helpful..
So, for now this feature not available for outside website?
and the whole sample is for facebook apps?

Comment: You could make it as Accepted answer if it has what you need.. :)